# Какие функции использовать, если нужно удалить варианты наборов определенных символов

Tags: php

Нужно удалить все сокращения, кроме определенного города (города разные). Они могут состоять из двух слов "Нижний Новгород" через пробел или дефис. Они могут иметь нижний регистр.

```
$arr = [
    'г. Москва',
    'г.Москва',
    'гор шмосква',
    'гор.москва',
    'Гор. Москва-бад',
    'г Нижний Новгород',
    'г. Нижний Новгород',
    'г.Нижний Новгород',
    'гор Нижний Новгород',
    'гор. Нижний Новгород',
    'гор.Нижний Новгород',
    'Город Нижний Новгород',
    'с. большая деревня'
];
```

Как это правильно сделать все? Не могу понять. Наверное надо вручную составить список этих сокращений и если есть соответствие обрезать его... по-другому я не знаю как еще. Либо обрезать до [первого пробела / точки]

Comment: Диневич у вас тут итак один город. Не понятно, что вам надо удалить?

Comment: @Эдуард во всех строках оставить "Москва" же!

Comment: @rjhdby Вы видимо телепат. в вопросе не названия города, а *кроме определенного города*

Comment: @rjhdby из чего это следует?!

Comment: где находятся города - в текстовом файле или в массиве или в переменной ?

Comment: @Alex в массиве

Comment: а `г.`, `гор.`, `Гор.` постоянны или может быть иное сокращение ?

Comment: @Эдуард богатый опыт допросов дает +100 к телепатии :)

Comment: А просто "Усть-Ужупинск", без префиксов, может быть?

Comment: @rjhdby однако в данном случае ваш опыт вас же и подвёл.

Comment: @Эдуард это еще почему? Правка вопроса таки наоборот увеличивает шансы того, что я был прав.

Comment: @Alex сокращения в принципе постоянны, я сначала хотел отделить город через точку с пробелом, но понял что иногда точки может не быть и просто пробел, но пробелы могут быть и в самом названии города

Comment: @АндрейДиневич уточните, что нужно получить в конечном счете?например если вводное слово "Москва", то нужно получить все строки где есть "Москва" ? т.е. г. Москва, г.Москва, гор.Москва ? или что-то другое ?

Comment: @Alex нет, города разные, нужно получить города без всяких гор. г. и так далее, только названия городов без лишних сокращений

Comment: @АндрейДиневич а мой вариант чем не подходит? А то смотрю, вы его молча минусите.

Comment: @АндрейДиневич в таком случае ответ Вам уже дан, если он Вас чем-то не устраивает, пожалуйста напишете чем именно.

Comment: @Эдуард если посмотреть в профиль автора, то можно увидеть, что он не голосовал против очень давно. Не обращайте внимания на минусы, это всего лишь -2, и поставить его может кто угодно по любой причине. Вы можете написать комментарий под своим ответом с просьбой пояснить причину минуса, иногда минусующие обосновывают свое действие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **UPD:** Обновил ответ с учётом ваших уточнений в комментариях: `"нужно получить города без всяких гор. г. и так далее, только названия городов без лишних сокращений"`

```
$arr = [
    'г. Москва',
    'г.Москва',
    'гор шмосква',
    'гор.москва',
    'Гор. Москва-бад',
    'г Нижний Новгород',
    'г. Нижний Новгород',
    'г.Нижний Новгород',
    'гор Нижний Новгород',
    'гор. Нижний Новгород',
    'гор.Нижний Новгород',
    'Город Нижний Новгород',
    'с. большая деревня'
];

$arr = array_map(function ($item) {
    $patt = '~^(?:г|с|гор|город)\.?\s?\b~iu';
    return preg_replace($patt, '', $item);
}, $arr);

echo '<pre>', print_r($arr, true), '</pre>';
```

> Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Москва
    [1] => Москва
    [2] => шмосква
    [3] => москва
    [4] => Москва-бад
    [5] => Нижний Новгород
    [6] => Нижний Новгород
    [7] => Нижний Новгород
    [8] => Нижний Новгород
    [9] => Нижний Новгород
    [10] => Нижний Новгород
    [11] => Нижний Новгород
    [12] => большая деревня
)
```

Comment: Но если город состоит из двух слов, например "гор Нижний Новгород", то как в этом случае быть?

Comment: @АндрейДиневич я это предусмотрел, проверьте - код должен отработать правильно.

Comment: проверял, не отрабатывет, обрезает по первое слово, оставляет "Нижний"

Comment: @АндрейДиневич добавьте в свой вопрос массив, для которого код не  сработал, и я чуть позже подправлю свой пример.

Comment: Добавил. Также названия могут начинаться с нижнего регистра

Comment: @АндрейДиневич проверяйте, подправил ответ!

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.

Comment: А скажите пожалуйста, можно ли еще по другому способу реализовать? Обрезать включительно до [первого пробела / или точки если нет пробела]?

Comment: @АндрейДиневич если у вас будет запись "Нижний Новгород", то  первая часть города будет обрезана. Поэтому просто обрезать по пробелам тут не выйдет.

Comment: А, ну да... если будет точка без пробела то пробел может оказаться в самом названии. Понятно. Спасибо еще раз. Хотя через костыль можно и таким способом, мне кажется. Через if если есть точка то обрезаем по точке а не по пробелу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68717/discussion-between--and--).